# Batch Script creating mutliple text files with incrementing numbers inside

Tags: image, text, batch-file, numbers

I'm trying to right a script that creates multiple text files from a list of image names but I need each of them to have an incremented number in the contents. So far I've come up with this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a i=0

for /f %%f in ( 'dir /b /A-D %1"*.jpg"' ) do (
    set /a i=i+1
    @rem echo %%f !i!
)

for %%a in (*.jpg) do echo caption= / %i% >> %%~na.txt
```

Which gives me the text files with the correct names and part of the content including the total number of files but I need each file created to be different so the first would say caption= 1 / 64 and the second 2 / 64 for example.

Can anyone please help me as I now have a sore head :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('dir *.jpg^|find "File(s)"') do (set numfiles=%%a)
set /a i=0
for /f %%f in ( 'dir /b /A-D %1"*.jpg"' ) do ( 
  set /a i=i+1 & echo caption= !i! / %numfiles% > %%~nf.txt
)
```

Comment: that just creates a file called %~na.txt with the total .jpgs out of all files in the folder, but it's a step in the right direction thanks :)

Comment: I used the wrong variable when I changed redirection to a file. I just tested echoing to the screen. Try it now.

Comment: OMG OMG!! Thankyou SOOOO MUCH! It works a charm and you've just saved me about 3hours work manually creating the files :)

Comment: I've just realised that it's counting the total number of files the folder not just the .jpg files, is there something simple I can change to do that? Thanks again

Comment: I've edited the code. Just add `*.jpg` after the `dir` in the first `For` loop